# Tensorflow accuracy score

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am creating a machine learning model in the form of regression.
I started with XGBoost to get my first estimates. However, these were not convincing enough (using XGB Regressor I got only 0.60 R2 Score).

So I started looking for solutions with neural networks and ended up using tensorflow. However, I am relatively new to this module and would like to know if there is an equivalent to `xgboost.score`?

The first code was using xgboost and I am working now on the second one, with tensorflow.

```
xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate = 0.30012, max_depth = 5, n_estimators = 180, subsample = 0.7, colsample_bylevel = 0.7, colsample_bytree = 0.7, min_child_weight = 4, reg_alpha = 10, reg_lambda = 10)
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Score on train data : " + str(xgb.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Score on validation data : " + str(xgb.score(X_val, y_val)))
```

The second one using TensorFlow:

```
tf.random.set_seed(123)  #first we set random seed

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = tf.keras.activations.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile( loss = tf.keras.losses.mae, #mae stands for mean absolute error
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), #stochastic GD
              metrics = ['mae'])
model.fit( X_train, y_train, epochs = 100)
```

How do I evaluate my tensorflow model using R2 Score?

Comment: A R2 score of 0.60 is not the same thing as 60% accuracy, accuracy is a metric only defined for classification, and meaningless for regression.

Comment: @PIXLNOOB I think you are mistakenly referring to accuracy instead of R2 score, this is creating some misunderstandings. I recommend you should update your answer and refer to R2 score, instead of accuracy.

Comment: I have suggested an edit, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`xgb.score` returns the R2 score, you can implement this metric in tensorflow from scratch,

```
def R_squared(y, y_pred):
  residual = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, y_pred)))
  total = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, tf.reduce_mean(y))))
  r2 = tf.subtract(1.0, tf.div(residual, total))
  return r2
```

When compiling your model, pass this function in the `metrics` parameter so that it shows up when evaluating and training your model, like this:

```
model.compile( loss = tf.keras.losses.mae, #mae stands for mean absolute error
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), #stochastic GD
              metrics = ['mae', R_squared])
```

When you evaluate your model using `model.evaluate`, as in below, the R2 score will appear,

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_val)
model.evaluate(y_pred, y_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand mean absolute errors then you can have a target return value from its functions.

It is accuracy means that is mean you need only one from the training and testing step. Refer to the function you need to understand about classifier and regression.

**[ Conditions ]:**

```
# [ Score ] : score – Mean accuracy of self.predict(X) wrt. y.
# https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html?highlight=xgboost.score#xgboost.XGBClassifier.score
# Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

# https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html?highlight=xgboost.score#xgboost.XGBRFRegressor.score
# Coefficients are defined only for linear learners
# Coefficients are only defined when the linear model is chosen as base learner (booster=gblinear). 
# It is not defined for other base learner types, such as tree learners (booster=gbtree).

# https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=xgboost.score&check_keywords=yes&area=default
# [py:method]: xgboost.XGBClassifier.score
#       Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels. ...
# [py:method]: xgboost.XGBRFClassifier.score
#       Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels. ...
# [py:method]: xgboost.XGBRFRegressor.score
#       Return the coefficient of determination of the prediction. Notes The \(R^2\) score used when calling ...
```

**[ Tensorflows expectation ]:**

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123313/tensorflow-accuracy-score
# Tensorflow accuracy score
```

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        print( "\ntrain mae: " + str( logs['mae'] ) )
    
    def on_test_end(self, logs=None):
        print( "\nevaluation mae: " + str( logs['mae'] ) )

custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.1, )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.mae

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['mae'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, validation_data=(dataset), validation_steps=1, batch_size=100, epochs=50, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

# [ Score ] : score – Mean accuracy of self.predict(X) wrt. y.
# https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html?highlight=xgboost.score#xgboost.XGBClassifier.score
# Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.


result = model.evaluate(
    dataset, batch_size=100, verbose=0, callbacks=[custom_callback]
)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array, callbacks=[custom_callback], verbose=1)
    
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:** mae is means accuracy value.

```
train mae: 3.8480560779571533
evaluation mae: 3.8665459156036377
```

**[ Result ]:**
 [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrb3y.png)

Comment: Again this does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: I explain what is means to accuracy score and how to achieve it with available focus method.

Comment: Sure but that was not the question, it is about R2 score, your comment effectively shows that you did not understand the question.

Comment: there is definitions I placed on the answer you may refer to web site links I attched.